# QVector::clear and QFile::close in QThreadPool

Tags: qt, qt5, qthread, qfile, qvector

I am using QThreadPool to run a worker that has function to create then clear huge QVector and write huge size of file.  However, every time one worker reach that lines (QVector::clear/QFile::close) all the threads got freeze and will continue when it is finished.

Is someone has any suggestion to overcome this situation ?  To have other threads still capable to run normal when in one of the worker run those two functions.  For QFile::close, I tried to use QFile::flush in my iteration instead of close() in the end of iterations, but it's not helping the performance.

This is the codes when the thread getting slower when clearing the vector

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_start_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "worker.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QSharedPointer>
#include <QThread>
#include <QThreadPool>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    on_start_pushButton_clicked();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_start_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int numProcess = 20;
    int numTraces = 10000;
    int numSamps = 8680;

    qDebug() << "main" << QThread::currentThread();
    QThreadPool *pool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();

    for (int i=0; i<numProcess; i++) {
        worker *w= new worker;
        w->setAutoDelete(true);

        w->setData(i+1, numTraces, numSamps);

        pool->start(w);
    }
}
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="start_pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>240</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Start</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

worker.h

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QRunnable>
#include <QThread>

class worker : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit worker(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent), QRunnable () {}
    ~worker() {}

    void setData(int id, int numTraces, int numSamps);

    void run();

signals:

public slots:

private:
    void clearVector();

    int id, numTraces, numSamps;
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

worker.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVector>

void worker::setData(int id1, int numTraces, int numSamps)
{
    this->id = id1;
    this->numTraces = numTraces;
    this->numSamps = numSamps;

    qDebug() << "setData" << id << numTraces << numSamps;
}

void worker::run()
{
    clearVector();
    qDebug() << "pool finished" << id << numTraces << numSamps << QThread::currentThread();
}

void worker::clearVector()
{
    QVector<QVector<float>> traces1, traces2;

    float progressWaypoint = 0.01f*numTraces;
    int progressPos = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numTraces; i++) {
        QVector<float> trace1, trace2;
        for (int j=0; j<numSamps; j++) {
            trace1.append(float(j));
            trace2.append(float(numSamps - j));
        }
        traces1.append(trace1);
        traces2.append(trace2);

        if (numTraces <= 100) {
            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        }
        else {
            if (i + 1 >= round(progressWaypoint*progressPos)) {
                QCoreApplication::processEvents();
                qDebug() << id << QThread::currentThread() << progressPos;
                progressPos++;
            }
        }
    }

    traces1.clear();
    traces2.clear();
}
```

Comment: I used to have the same problem quite a long time ago. Finally, I found that cleaning very big Qt container classes and flushing files takes a long time on debug builds but they are very smooth on a release build. try it and inform me if I have to add this as an answer.

Comment: I tried in release mode but unfortunately it's still acted same when one of worker thread reach clear function

Comment: why are you calling ```QCoreApplication::processEvents()``` ?

Comment: another hint , check how many threads are allowed to be created by calling  ```QThreadPool::globalInstance()->maxThreadCount()```

Comment: Don't call processEvents, there's no point in a worker thread (if it is even thread-safe)

Comment: This is not a reproducible example.

Comment: @SoheilArmin : I use processEvents to make my other interface not freeze during intense iteration.   I tried to reduce the number of cores, still not improve the performance

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld : thanks for your suggestion,  I take it out processEvents in the loop but the result still same

Comment: @MaximPaperno : Do you want to see *.h files and main.cpp as well ?

Comment: Yes, something I can (more or less) just paste into my test project and run. Or, more likely, be able to spot a possible problem with the code you post. For example, if you needed `processEvents` in the first place it suggests the worker is not really running in a separate thread somehow. But that's impossible to tell from the bits you provided so far.

Comment: @MaximPaperno I added more codes there

Comment: Thanks for posting the full code. So far, breaking it down to even more minimal code, I can only confirm that de-allocating a large QVector does indeed seem to preempt other threads until it is done. Testing on Windows 7 so far, Qt 5.12. Actually it only works at all with MSVC, with MinGw the whole thing crashes before even finishing the worker loop (before any de-allocation). I have 16 v-cores in my test rig, (so only max. of 16 threads, -1 for GUI), so no way it'll run 20 of these in parallel. But even reducing the count to 5 or 10 still has long lags during de-allocation.

Comment: Also it'll hang the same w/out `QVector::clear()` calls when the vector goes out of scope and is destroyed.  BTW, `clear()` doesn't actually de-allocate the memory (check the Qt docs) so in this case it just slows things down even more (and that's not where it hangs anyway, that happens during the actual de-allocation).

Comment: Calling `reserve()` may also help before starting your loops.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem.  Testing on Windows, Qt 5.12.4.

One thing I've determined so far is that `std::vector` seems to perform better in this case.  But it's still quite a long time, and does affect other threads on the system, making the UI only somewhat-responsive.  But better than `QVector`.

Also, these are large numbers and require significant memory. On my 32-bit MinGw build it crashes with out of memory errors when I try to use > 2 threads. The tests were therefore done with 64b MSVC2017. Test machine has 8-cores @ 3.? GHz w/64GB RAM.

Here are some timing results (code used to generate this is below):

```
1 worker with 2 `std::vector`s:
    Worker 1 finished (ms) 1648
    Last worker finished after 1649 total ms.

5 workers with 2 `std::vector`s:
    Worker 1 finished (ms) 44363
    Worker 2 finished (ms) 44386
    Worker 3 finished (ms) 44388
    Worker 4 finished (ms) 44401
    Worker 5 finished (ms) 44448
    Last worker finished after 44449 total ms.

10 workers with 2 `std::vector`s:
    Worker 4 finished (ms) 84910
    Worker 7 finished (ms) 92701
    Worker 2 finished (ms) 111590
    Worker 8 finished (ms) 144678
    Worker 9 finished (ms) 145378
    Worker 5 finished (ms) 169067
    Worker 3 finished (ms) 211629
    Worker 1 finished (ms) 220098
    Worker 10 finished (ms) 249356
    Worker 6 finished (ms) 253452
    Last worker finished after 253453 total ms.


1 worker with 2 `QVector`s:
    Worker 1 finished (ms) 1871
    Last worker finished after 1872 total ms.

5 workers with 2 `QVector`s:
    Worker 1 finished (ms) 36492
    Worker 3 finished (ms) 58157
    Worker 5 finished (ms) 79132
    Worker 2 finished (ms) 84612
    Worker 4 finished (ms) 84819
    Last worker finished after 84820 total ms.

10 workers with 2 `QVector`s:
    Worker 7 finished (ms) 234770
    Worker 8 finished (ms) 247531
    Worker 9 finished (ms) 261346
    Worker 1 finished (ms) 261924
    Worker 4 finished (ms) 270520
    Worker 2 finished (ms) 275740
    Worker 10 finished (ms) 290605
    Worker 3 finished (ms) 293575
    Worker 6 finished (ms) 296074
    Worker 5 finished (ms) 296249
    Last worker finished after 296361 total ms.
```

At a certain point between 5 and 10 threads even `std::vector` seems to start "tripping over itself." This is also obvious in GUI responsiveness (somewhat responsive at 5, hardly at all at 10).

As mentioned in the comments of the OP, the delay happens during de-allocation of the large vectors `traces1` and `traces2`, not, apparently, during `clear()` (or `swap()` for that matter). But the only way to determine this is with a debugger because once it hits the end of the `clearVector()` function the thread is essentially hung up (trying to timestamp this with a timer is useless).

I also tried using only 1 vector "set" inside `Worker` (see code).  Huge difference:

```
10 workers with 1 `std::vector`:
    Worker 5 finished (ms) 4125
    Worker 4 finished (ms) 4139
    Worker 1 finished (ms) 4141
    Worker 6 finished (ms) 4153
    Worker 10 finished (ms) 4161
    Worker 9 finished (ms) 4177
    Worker 7 finished (ms) 4197
    Worker 3 finished (ms) 4216
    Worker 8 finished (ms) 4209
    Worker 2 finished (ms) 4221
    Last worker finished after 4222 total ms.

10 workers with 1 `QVector`:
    Worker 10 finished (ms) 4308
    Worker 2 finished (ms) 4358
    Worker 1 finished (ms) 4373
    Worker 3 finished (ms) 4385
    Worker 8 finished (ms) 4391
    Worker 4 finished (ms) 4400
    Worker 6 finished (ms) 4404
    Worker 7 finished (ms) 4401
    Worker 5 finished (ms) 4409
    Worker 9 finished (ms) 4406
    Last worker finished after 4410 total ms.
```

Here's my test "rig":

```cpp
#include <QRunnable>
#include <QThread>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QtWidgets>

#define USE_QVECTOR 0
#define NUM_VECTORS 2
#define USE_CLEAR   0
#define USE_SWAP    0

class Worker : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
#if USE_QVECTOR
    typedef QVector<int> vect_t;
    typedef QVector<vect_t> vectVect_t;
#else
    typedef std::vector<int> vect_t;
    typedef std::vector<vect_t> vectVect_t;
#endif

    explicit Worker(int id, int traces, int samples, QObject *parent = nullptr) :
      QObject(parent), QRunnable(),
      id(id), numTraces(traces), numSamps(samples)
    {}

    void run() override
    {
      qDebug() << "worker starting" << id << numTraces << numSamps << QThread::currentThread();
      emit progressChanged(id, -1);
      tim.start();
      clearVector();
      emit progressChanged(id, tim.elapsed());
    }

  signals:
    void progressChanged(int id, int pos) const;

  private:
    void clearVector()
    {
      vectVect_t traces1, traces2;
      traces1.reserve(numTraces);
      if (NUM_VECTORS > 1)
        traces2.reserve(numTraces);
      float progressWaypoint = 0.01f * numTraces;
      int progressPos = 0;
      for (int i=0; i < numTraces; i++) {
        vect_t trace1, trace2;
        trace1.reserve(numSamps);
        if (NUM_VECTORS > 1)
          trace2.reserve(numSamps);
        for (int j=0; j < numSamps; j++) {
          trace1.push_back(j);
          if (NUM_VECTORS > 1)
            trace2.push_back(numSamps - j);
        }
        traces1.push_back(trace1);
        if (NUM_VECTORS > 1)
          traces2.push_back(trace2);

        if (i + 1 >= round(progressWaypoint * progressPos))
          emit progressChanged(id, progressPos++);
      }
      qDebug() << "Vectors populated in" << tim.elapsed();

      if (USE_CLEAR) {
        // Clearing the vectors slows the process down a bit but its not where the delay is.
        traces1.clear();
        if (NUM_VECTORS > 1)
          traces2.clear();
      }
      if (USE_SWAP) {
        // swap is very fast but it doesn't help overall performance
        vectVect_t blank;
        traces1.swap(blank);
        if (NUM_VECTORS > 1)
          traces2.swap(blank);
      }
    }

    int id, numTraces, numSamps;
    QElapsedTimer tim;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  // UI setup
  QDialog d;
  d.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
  QPushButton *pbStart = new QPushButton("Start", &d);
  QSpinBox *sbThreads = new QSpinBox(&d);
  sbThreads->setValue(5);
  QSpinBox *sbTraces = new QSpinBox(&d);
  sbTraces->setMaximum(10000);
  sbTraces->setValue(10000);
  QSpinBox *sbSamps = new QSpinBox(&d);
  sbSamps->setMaximum(10000);
  sbSamps->setValue(8680);
  QHBoxLayout *btnLo = new QHBoxLayout();
  btnLo->setSpacing(6);
  btnLo->addWidget(pbStart);
  btnLo->addWidget(new QLabel("Thrds:", &d));
  btnLo->addWidget(sbThreads, 1);
  btnLo->addWidget(new QLabel("Traces:", &d));
  btnLo->addWidget(sbTraces, 1);
  btnLo->addWidget(new QLabel("Samps:", &d));
  btnLo->addWidget(sbSamps, 1);
  d.layout()->addItem(btnLo);
  // Text box for showing results
  QTextEdit *e = new QTextEdit(&d);
  e->setReadOnly(true);
  e->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
  d.layout()->addWidget(e);

  QElapsedTimer tim;  // total elapsed timer
  QVector<int> finished;  // keep track of finished workers

  // Set up workers on button click.
  QObject::connect(pbStart, &QPushButton::clicked, &d, [&]()
  {
    const int threads = sbThreads->value(),
        traces = sbTraces->value(),
        samples = sbSamps->value();

    QThreadPool *pool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();
    //pool->setStackSize(samples * 4 * traces * threads);
    qDebug() << "Pool max. threads:" << pool->maxThreadCount() << "Stack size:" << pool->stackSize();
    pbStart->setDisabled(true);
    finished.clear();
    tim.start();

    for (int i=0; i < threads; i++) {
      Worker *w = new Worker(i+1, traces, samples);

      // Show messages on worker progress updates
      QObject::connect(w, &Worker::progressChanged, &d, [e, pbStart, threads, &tim, &finished](int id, int pos)
      {
        const QString msg = QStringLiteral("Worker %1 %2 %3")
            .arg(id)
            .arg(pos < 0 ? "started" : pos > 100 ? "finished (ms)" : "progress")
            .arg(pos);
        e->append(msg);
        if (pos > 100) {
          finished << id;
          if (finished.count() == threads) {
            e->append(QStringLiteral("Last worker finished after %1 total ms.").arg(tim.elapsed()));
            pbStart->setEnabled(true);
          }
        }
        e->ensureCursorVisible();
      }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

      w->setAutoDelete(true);
      pool->start(w);
      qDebug() << "Queued worker" << i+1 << "with active thread count:" << pool->activeThreadCount();
    }
  });

  d.show();
  return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

[image]

---

**ADDED**: Using fixed-size arrays instead of vectors. Obviously in real code some care would need to be taken to ensure the array indexes are actually valid. (Also of course one could populate the `traces1` and `traces2` arrays directly in the inner loop, w/out the intermediate `trace1/2`, but NVM that for now. :)

```cpp
    void clearVector()
    {
      float progressWaypoint = 0.01f * numTraces;
      int progressPos = 0;
      // volatile to help make sure the compiler isn't just optimizing these out.
      volatile int *traces1[10000], *traces2[10000];
      for (int i=0; i < numTraces; i++) {
        volatile int trace1[10000], trace2[10000];
        for (int j=0; j < numSamps; j++) {
          trace1[j] = j;
          trace2[j] = (numSamps - j);
        }
        traces1[i] = trace1;
        traces2[i] = trace2;
        if (i + 1 >= round(progressWaypoint * progressPos))
          emit progressChanged(id, progressPos++);
      }
      // also use a value from the populated arrays to make sure they really exist.
      qDebug() << "Vectors populated in" << tim.elapsed() << traces1[0][0] << traces2[5][5];
    }
```

I had to add `100` to the timer number because each thread finishes in < 100ms.

```
    void run() override {
      ...
      clearVector();
      emit progressChanged(id, tim.elapsed() + 100);
    }
```

With 20 threads (16 immediate and 4 get queued) and 10K each of "traces" and "samples" I get:

> Last worker finished after 332 total ms.

Also this runs no problem on my 32-bit MinGW build with 20 threads. Same exec times.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis.  From there, it looks like the bottleneck happens when de-allocating the vector.  Do you think is the way qt worked or related to the OS also ?

Comment: @zufryy Maybe I'm missing something (like actually using the values in the populated arrays), but with fixed-sized arrays instead of vectors it is almost instant.  Like 30-100ms "instant", even with 20 thread requests (some of which get queued). I'm adding an updated `clearVectors()` to my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Just wondering thought, when you declaring `volatile int *traces1[10000], *traces2[10000];` , do we need to delete that pointer so it won't have any memory leaks ?